# Price and process of rewiring a bus to run from solar power?

Tags: wiring, bus, solar-energy

I want to rewire an omnibus from running off of gasoline to running off of solar panels. Not my field.

What are some things that would have to be done? Specifically, what would it entail to completely change how a bus runs? And just rough estimate pricing as a side. Also, if you know any good sources for me to go to to find out about this, that would be helpful. I don't know where to even begin....

Comment: check out "Solarolla Electric Vehicles" on Facebook, they are doing this. They helped these folks solar-ize an International E-Star van: https://www.routedelsol.com/

Answer (score 1):

Even if you go all electric, you'll have to either rebuild a much less safe and heavy vehicle out of carbon fibre composites, or accept that a ton of your power is going to be coming from the grid, or you'll be limited to stopping places where you can set up a large array of panels to recharge the bus.  Might take a few days or a week with enough panels.

If you're keeping your gas engine and just want to charge the battery with solar in addition, that's not such a big deal.  Wire panels to charge controller, increase bank size if necessary.

So for the question you appear to be asking,

What would have to be done?

Rebuild omnibus in carbon fibre composite and aluminum, improving aerodynamics and maximising sun exposed area.  Eliminate all non essentials.  Plan where the bus will be travelling.  Purchase, mount and wire panels suited specifically to those lighting conditions.  Design lithium-ion battery array and charger that is somehow safe inside carbon fibre and aluminum deathtrap.  Cautiously connect battery.

Specifically, what would it entail to completely change how a bus runs?

To some degree, vehicles are designed around their engines and fuel.  If you're taking out the engine, see above, that's going to be a complete redesign.

Rough estimate pricing?

Lots, man.  Like, so much, like, some more a lot.  It would cost a substantial amount of money to make a decent estimate of the cost.

As far as the more reasonable question of adding solar, keeping the engine and increasing the battery bank, meh, couple grand, maybe as much as 50, depends how many batteries and panels you can safely fit and what type of panel, and fit and finish of course.

As far as sources, I recommend you shop around to get an idea of what the parts *can* do.  Search for the best panel, the cheapest panel, the best deal, and dig into the datasheets, learn about light conditions, figure out how many of each panel type you can fit on your microbus(film types might let you keep a sleekish look while fitting more panels if you have extensive autobody skills), and how much power you'll be able to generate at peak(brightest light, best angle) and over a day.  Then you have a rough idea of how much power you might have and you can figure out what you can use it for.  Once you have an idea of what you can and want to use that amount of power for, start figuring out how much power you'll use and when, because the longer you store it, the larger your battery bank must be.  If you want to still have your fridge or lights working after 4 days without sun, you need a much larger battery bank than you would need if the battery only has to last overnight.

You'll end up with a tradeoff with space used by the batteries and come to some compromise, and aside from the fact that the engine lets you move the thing around, at some point you'll be glad for the backup generator.  Or get an actual backup generator designed for the purpose and leave the alternator to charge just it's own battery.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from K H is accurate, but also a bit sarcastic, which can be hard to read. So here's a more direct answer: You cannot do the thing you want to do.

A bus I randomly picked off the internet is 8.5 feet wide x 40 feet long. (The exact dimensions won't matter much.) The total energy of the sun hitting a horizontal surface on the earth peaks at about 27 watts per sqft at the equator (averaged over the whole day/night cycle; it's higher when the sun is up.)

That's about 9 kilowatts if the entire top surface of your bus is covered with 100% perfect solar panels at the equator. Unfortunately, the best availalble solar panels are about 27% efficient, so that's about 2400 watts actually available. (In Canada, divide by 2; in the USA, somewhere in between.)

A gasoline engine is about 50% efficient, and gasoline has about 30 kWh per gallon. It looks like buses get about 5 miles to the gallon. If you're going at highway speeds (65 miles per hour), it will be burning ... about 200 kilowatts. [That's not totally fair; it's probably more efficient at highway speeds. But we're being approximate.]

So if your electric bus has the best possible solar panels, covering the entire top surface with no unused space, and the drive system is perfectly efficient, and you drive it at the equator under perfect sun conditions and never in the shade ... you'd be able to drive about 17 minutes a day. In North America you'd get maybe 10 minutes.

My math is rough, and I'm sure other people can improve on it, but the fundamental lesson here is that fossil fuels like gasoline are VERY energy dense, which is why they're hard to beat for transportation applications.

This is why fast charging is so important for electric cars, and people talk about battery swap stations on occasion. The amount of power it takes to run a car is *immense*, and just pumping enough juice out of the grid and into the car is a huge challenge. Compared to that, solar panels are just downright anemic. The impossibly-perfect array of solar panels I just described above, the size of a bus roof, puts out 2.4 kW, averaged over the day-night cycle. A home Tesla charger puts out about 12 kW, by comparison, but it's charging a MUCH smaller, MUCH more efficient vehicle, and even then it takes all night to charge just for a day's commute; supercharging stations are needed for supplementation when doing a road trip. (Tesla superchargers can supply up to 120 kW.)